# how to access localstorage data in nextjs

Tags: next.js, token

i am new to next js and have shifted from react js. on login I am saving a token in localstorage and accessing later for authentication.
in next js I am getting error as it is server based
Please suggest the way to achieve the task mentioned above in next js

Thank you in advance

Comment: check this helps or not https://hackernoon.com/storing-and-retrieving-data-in-nextjs-using-localstorage-and-typescript

Answer (score 1):

you can use localStorage only in client components because its a browser feature and the code should run in browser. if you need something that needs to be accessible in both client and server components, you should store it in cookies.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies